# How do I get my Tetris game to play as soon as the window opens

Tags: java

I have a fully functional tetris game that previously had start and pause buttons. I have now removed them but I am struggling to make the game work automatically.
Currently this game does not start at all.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class Tetris extends JPanel {

    //
    // STATIC MEMBERS
    //

    private final static int INITIAL_DELAY = 1000;
    private final static byte ROWS = 20;
    private final static byte COLUMNS = 10;
    private final static int EMPTY = -1;
    private final static int DELETED_ROWS_PER_LEVEL = 5;

    private final static Color PIECE_COLORS[] = {
            new Color(0xFF00FF), // fucia
            new Color(0xDC143C), // crimson
            new Color(0x00CED1), // dark turquoise
            new Color(0xFFD700), // gold
            new Color(0x32CD32), // lime green
            new Color(0x008080), // teal
            new Color(0xFFA500), // orange
    };

    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COLORS[] = {
            new Color(0xFFDAB9), // peachpuff
            new Color(0xFFC0CB), // pink
            new Color(0xFF99CC), // hot pink
            new Color(0x0099CC), // sky blue
            new Color(0x9966CC), // lavender
    };

    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0x99FFCC);

    //   *    **   *    *    *    *
    //   *    *    *    **   **   **   **
    //   *    *    **    *   *    *    **
    //   *
    //   0    1    2    3    4    5    6
    private final static boolean PIECE_BITS[][][] = {

            {
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, false, true, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, false, true, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
            },
    };

    private static boolean tmp_grid[][] = new boolean[4][4]; // scratch space
    private static Random random = new Random();

    private static class TetrisLabel extends Label {
        private final static Font LABEL_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18);
        private TetrisLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
            setFont(LABEL_FONT);
        }
        private void addValue(int val) {
            setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(getText())) + val ));
        }
    }

    //
    // INSTANCE DATA
    //

    private int grid[][] = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    private int next_piece_grid[][] = new int[4][4];
    private int num_rows_deleted = 0;
    private GridCanvas game_grid = new GridCanvas(grid, true);
    private GridCanvas next_piece_canvas = new GridCanvas(next_piece_grid, false);
    private Timer timer;
    private TetrisPiece cur_piece;
    private TetrisPiece next_piece = randomPiece();
    private TetrisLabel rows_deleted_label = new TetrisLabel("0");
    private TetrisLabel level_label = new TetrisLabel("1");
    private TetrisLabel score_label = new TetrisLabel("0");
    private TetrisLabel high_score_label = new TetrisLabel("");

    //
    // INNER CLASSES
    //

    private class TetrisButton extends Button {
        public TetrisButton(String label) {
            super(label);
        }
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(120, super.getPreferredSize().height);
        }
    }

    public class TetrisPiece {

        private boolean squares[][];
        private int type;
        private Point position = new Point(3, -4); // -4 to start above top row
        public int getX() { return position.x; }
        public int getY() { return position.y; }
        public void setX(int newx) { position.x = newx; }
        public void setY(int newy) { position.y = newy; }
        public void setPosition(int newx, int newy) { setX(newx); setY(newy);

        }

        public TetrisPiece(int type) {
            this.type = type;
            this.squares = new boolean[4][4];
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    this.squares[i][j] = PIECE_BITS[type][i][j];
        }

        public boolean canStepDown() {
            synchronized(timer) {
                cut();
                position.y++;
                boolean OK = canPaste();
                position.y--;
                paste();
                return OK;
            }
        }

        public boolean canPaste() {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                    int to_x = j + position.x;
                    int to_y = i + position.y;
                    if(squares[i][j]) { // piece contains this square?
                        if(0 > to_x || to_x >= COLUMNS // square too far left or right?
                                || to_y >= ROWS) // square off bottom?
                        {
                            return false;
                            // note: it's always considered OK to paste a square
                            // *above* the grid though attempting to do so does nothing.
                            // This allows the user to move a piece before it drops
                            // completely into view.
                        }
                        if(to_y >= 0 && grid[to_y][to_x] != EMPTY)
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void stepDown() {
            position.y++;
        }

        public void cut() {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    if(squares[i][j] && position.y+i>=0)
                        grid[position.y + i][position.x + j] = EMPTY;
        }

        /**
         * Paste the color info of this piece into the given grid
         */
        public void paste(int into[][]) {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    if(squares[i][j] && position.y+i>=0)
                        into[position.y + i][position.x + j] = type;
        }

        /**
         * No argument version assumes pasting into main game grid
         */
        public void paste() {
            paste(grid);
        }

        public void rotate() {
            // copy the piece's data into a temp array
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    tmp_grid[i][j] = squares[i][j];
            // copy back rotated 90 degrees
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    squares[j][i] = tmp_grid[i][3-j];
        }
        public void rotateBack() {
            // copy originally saved version back
            // this of course assumes this call was preceeded by
            // a call to rotate() for the same piece
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    squares[i][j] = tmp_grid[i][j];
        }

        // this method is a bit of a hack to check for the case
        // where a piece may be safely on the grid but have one or more
        // rows of empty squares that are above the grid and therefore OK
        public boolean isTotallyOnGrid() {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                if(position.y + i >= 0)
                    return true; //everything from here down is on grid
                // this row is above grid so look for non-empty squares
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    if(squares[i][j])
                        return false;
            }
            System.err.println("TetrisPiece.isTotallyOnGrid internal error");
            return false;
        }
    } // end class TetrisPiece


    private class Timer extends Thread {
        private long m_delay;
        private boolean m_paused = true;
        private boolean m_fast = false;
        private ActionListener m_cb;
        public Timer(long delay, ActionListener cb) {
            setDelay(delay);
            m_cb = cb;
        }

        public void setPaused(boolean pause) {
            m_paused = pause;
            if(m_paused) {
            }
            else {
                synchronized(this) {
                    this.notify();
                }
            }
        }
        public boolean isPaused() { return m_paused; }
        public void setDelay(long delay) { m_delay = delay; }
        public boolean isRunning() { return !m_paused; }
        public void setFast(boolean fast) {
            m_fast = fast;
            if(m_fast) {
                try {
                    this.checkAccess();
                    this.interrupt(); // no exception, so OK to interrupt
                } catch(SecurityException se) {}
            }
        }
        public boolean isFast() { return m_fast; }
        public void faster() {
            m_delay = (int)(m_delay * .9); //increase the speed exponentially in reverse
        }
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    sleep(m_fast ? 30 : m_delay);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                if(m_paused) {
                    try {
                        synchronized(this) {
                            this.wait();
                        }
                    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                }
                synchronized(this) {
                    m_cb.actionPerformed(null);
                }
            }
        }
    } // end class Timer

    private class GridCanvas extends DoubleBufferedCanvas {
        private int grid[][];
        private boolean paint_background;
        public GridCanvas(int[][] grid, boolean do_background) {
            this.grid = grid;
            paint_background = do_background;
            clear();
        }

        private void clear() {
            for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<grid[0].length; j++)
                    grid[i][j] = EMPTY;
        }
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(grid[0].length * 30, grid.length * 30);
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g = this.startPaint(g); // returned g paints into offscreen image
            int width = this.getSize().width;
            int height = this.getSize().height;
            g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            int cell_size, xstart, ystart;
            double panel_aspect_ratio = (double)width/height;
            double grid_aspect_ratio = (double)grid[0].length/grid.length;
            if(panel_aspect_ratio > grid_aspect_ratio) {
                // extra space on sides
                cell_size = (int)((double)height/grid.length + 0.5);
                xstart = (int)(width/2 - (grid[0].length/2.0 * cell_size + 0.5));
                ystart = 0;
            }
            else {
                // extra vertical space
                cell_size = (int)((double)width/grid[0].length + 0.5);
                xstart = 0;
                ystart = (int)(height/2 - (grid.length/2.0 * cell_size + 0.5));
            }
            if(paint_background) {
                g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLORS[(num_rows_deleted / DELETED_ROWS_PER_LEVEL) % BACKGROUND_COLORS.length]);
                g.fillRect(xstart, ystart, COLUMNS*cell_size, ROWS*cell_size);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<grid[0].length; j++) {
                    if(grid[i][j] != EMPTY) {
                        g.setColor(PIECE_COLORS[grid[i][j]]);
                        int x = xstart + j*cell_size;
                        int y = ystart + i*cell_size;
                        g.fill3DRect(x, y, cell_size, cell_size, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.endPaint(); // paints accumulated image in one shot
        }
    } // end class GridCanvas



    //
    // INSTANCE METHODS
    //

    private TetrisPiece randomPiece() {
        int rand = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
        return new TetrisPiece(rand % (PIECE_COLORS.length));
    }

    private void installNewPiece() {
        next_piece_canvas.clear();
        cur_piece = next_piece;
        cur_piece.setPosition(3, -4); //-4 to start above top of grid
        if(cur_piece.canPaste()) {
            next_piece = randomPiece();
            next_piece.setPosition(0, 0);
            next_piece.paste(next_piece_grid);
            next_piece_canvas.repaint();
        }
        else
            gameOver();
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        timer.setPaused(true);
        int score = Integer.parseInt(score_label.getText());
        int high_score = high_score_label.getText().length() > 0 ?
                Integer.parseInt(high_score_label.getText()) : 0;
        if(score > high_score)
            high_score_label.setText("" + score);

    }

    private boolean rowIsFull(int row) {
        for(int i=0; i<COLUMNS; i++)
            if(grid[row][i] == EMPTY)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    private int countFullRows() {
        int n_full_rows = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
            if(rowIsFull(i))
                n_full_rows++;
        return n_full_rows;
    }

    private void removeRow(int row) {
        for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++)
            grid[row][j] = EMPTY;
        for(int i=row; i>0; i--) {
            for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = grid[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeFullRows() {
        int n_full = countFullRows();
        score_label.addValue((int) (10 * Math.pow(2, n_full) - 10)); //give points exponentially
        if(n_full == 0)
            return;
        if(num_rows_deleted / DELETED_ROWS_PER_LEVEL != (num_rows_deleted+n_full) / DELETED_ROWS_PER_LEVEL) {
            timer.faster();
            level_label.addValue(n_full / DELETED_ROWS_PER_LEVEL + 1);
            level_label.repaint();
        }
        rows_deleted_label.addValue(n_full);
        num_rows_deleted += n_full;
        for(int i=ROWS-1; i>=0; i--)
            while(rowIsFull(i))
                removeRow(i);
        game_grid.repaint();
    }

    public void start() {
        timer = new Timer(INITIAL_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                synchronized(timer) {
                    if(cur_piece.canStepDown()) {
                        cur_piece.cut();
                        cur_piece.stepDown();
                        cur_piece.paste();
                    }
                    else { // it hit something
                        timer.setFast(false);
                        if( ! cur_piece.isTotallyOnGrid())
                            gameOver();
                        else {
                            removeFullRows();
                            installNewPiece();
                        }
                    }
                }
                game_grid.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start(); // pauses immediately
    }



    public void init() {

        installNewPiece();


        //create key listener for rotating, moving left, moving right
        KeyListener key_listener = new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(timer.isPaused()) //don't do anything if game is paused
                    return;
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 37 || e.getKeyCode() == 39) { //left or right arrow pressed
                    int dir = e.getKeyCode() == 37 ? -1 : 1;
                    synchronized(timer) {
                        cur_piece.cut();
                        cur_piece.setX(cur_piece.getX() + dir); // try to move
                        if( ! cur_piece.canPaste())
                            cur_piece.setX(cur_piece.getX() - dir); // undo move
                        cur_piece.paste();
                    }
                    game_grid.repaint();
                }
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) { //rotate
                    synchronized(timer) {
                        cur_piece.cut();
                        cur_piece.rotate();
                        if( ! cur_piece.canPaste())
                            cur_piece.rotateBack();
                        cur_piece.paste();
                    }
                    game_grid.repaint();
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) { //down arrow pressed; drop piece
                    timer.setFast(true);
                }
            }
        };

        // add the key listener to all components that might get focus
        // so that it'll work regardless of which has focus
        //start_newgame_butt.addKeyListener(key_listener);
        //pause_resume_butt.addKeyListener(key_listener);



        // finaly, add all the main panels to the applet panel
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        this.add(game_grid);
        this.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.validate();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame("Joshua Ogunnote - 1404528");
        Tetris tetris = new Tetris();
        frame.add(tetris);
        tetris.init();
        tetris.start();


        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(250,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
} // end class Tetris


class DoubleBufferedCanvas extends Canvas {
    private Image mActiveOffscreenImage = null;
    private Dimension mOffscreenSize = new Dimension(-1,-1);
    private Graphics mActiveOffscreenGraphics = null;
    private Graphics mSystemGraphics = null;

    DoubleBufferedCanvas() {
        /*
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });*/
    }

    /**
     * NOTE: when extending applets:
     * this overrides update() to *not* erase the background before painting
     */
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public Graphics startPaint (Graphics sysgraph) {
        mSystemGraphics = sysgraph;
        // Initialize if this is the first pass or the size has changed
        Dimension d = getSize();
        if ((mActiveOffscreenImage == null) ||
                (d.width != mOffscreenSize.width) ||
                (d.height != mOffscreenSize.height))
        {
            mActiveOffscreenImage = createImage(d.width, d.height);
            mActiveOffscreenGraphics = mActiveOffscreenImage.getGraphics();
            mOffscreenSize = d;
            mActiveOffscreenGraphics.setFont(getFont());
        }
        //mActiveOffscreenGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, mOffscreenSize.width, mOffscreenSize.height);
        return mActiveOffscreenGraphics;
    }

    public void endPaint () {
        // Start copying the offscreen image to this canvas
        // The application will begin drawing into the other one while this happens
        mSystemGraphics.drawImage(mActiveOffscreenImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the event dispatching thread. Swing is not thread safe, so to ensure all goes well when the application launches kindly try enclosing the frame display code in your main withing the runnables's run() method as below:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(){

               @Override
               public void run(){
                     Frame frame = new Frame("Joshua Ogunnote - 1404528");
                     Tetris tetris = new Tetris();
                     frame.add(tetris);
                     frame.setVisible(true);
               }

        }
}
```

Comment: I am getting three errors. Firstly with your " javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater()" error message is saying that it can't be applied secound error message is with "@Override" it's saying that Annotations are not allowed here. Final error message is with "run()" and it is saying that it is expecting an ";" I hope that is helpful.